# How do you search for substring in ansible group_names?

Tags: ansible

For a group name `hello`, I use the following condition in ansible and it works fine:

```
when: "'hello' in group_names "
```

Is there a way to use a regular expression if I want to match for keywords `hello` in the following group_names:

```
hello
somewhere_hello
hello123
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [select](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#select) and [count](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#length) items with filters:

```
when: group_names | select('search','hello') | list | count > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use join and search:

```
when: group_names|join(" ")|search("hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2.9 search is a test and not a filter:

```
group_names is search("hello")
```